# How to connect Amazon Elasticache with Redsmin Redis GUI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elasticache, redsmin

AWS Elasticache currently does not allow **IP-range based access control**. Therefore I don't know how to connect AWS ElastiCache cluster to [Redsmin Redis GUI](https://redsmin.com).

Answer (score 0):

To connect your AWS ElastiCache cluster to Redsmin you will need to add two IPTables rules to one of your EC2 instance so it will be able to act as a proxy.

There are two scenario:

**1 - If you have an EC2 instance in the same subnet as your Redis Elasticache**

Note:

- This will only work if the EC2 instance you connect to is in the same subnet as your Elasticache Redis instance.
- The following example will state that your Elasticache private IP is 172.31.5.13 and is running on port 6379.
- The following example will state that your EC2 private IP is 172.31.5.14 and its public IP is 52.50.145.87.

Now:

- Connect to your EC2 instance through SSH
- Then run (don't forget to change `172.31.5.13:6379` by the ElastiCache IP and port number):

`sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6379 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.31.5.13:6379`

- Then:

`run:sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 172.31.5.13 --dport 6379 -j SNAT --to-source 172.31.5.14`

- `sudo service iptables save`
- Again don't forget to change `172.31.5.14` with your local EC2 server private IP. Same goes for `172.31.5.13` and `6379`, replace them your Elasticache IP and port number.
- Add a rule in the security group to allow inbound request from Redsmin IP `62.210.222.165`, protocol=TCP, port=6379
- Add a new Direct Server in Redsmin with the connection string: `redis://52.50.145.87:6379`, done!

If you have any issue or questions with the above steps, don't hesitate, [contact us](https://redsmin.uservoice.com/clients/widgets/classic_widget?mode=support&locale=en&forum_id=173279&contact_us=true&custom_template_id=25441&context=site2&embed_type=lightbox&contact_enabled=true&feedback_enabled=false&strings=e30%3D&smartvote=true&default_mode=support&referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fredsmin.uservoice.com%2Fknowledgebase%2Farticles%2F734646-amazon-redis-elasticache-and-redsmin), we are happy to help!

**2 - If you don't have an EC2 instance in the same subnet as your Redis ElastiCache**

Follow this [Amazon tutorial to setup a NAT instance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html), be sure to setup it **on the same subnet as your ElastiCache server**. Now follow the steps from the section above.

Comment: When running 'service iptables save', I get this error. Any ideas what is causing this?

"The service command supports only basic LSB actions (start, stop, restart, try-restart, reload, force-reload, status). For other actions, please try to use systemctl."

Comment: It was an issue with the AWS AMI I was using. I used a different one that had iptables installed.